# Shifting rows per index with a different value in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Below is the sample data:

```
sample_col = ["col1","col2","col3","col4", "col5"]
sample_data = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20]]
sample = pd.DataFrame(data = data_data, columns = data_col)

sample

   col1  col2  col3  col4 col5
 0  1    2     3     4    5
 1  6    7     8     9    10
 2  11   12    13    14   15
 3  16   17    18    19   20
 
m = [0,1,2,1]
```

I need to shift each row in the data frame sample by the corresponding value in the list `m`.

The output is supposed to look like this

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4 col5
 0  1    2     3     4    5
 1  NaN  6     7     8    9
 2  NaN  NaN   11    12   13
 3  NaN  16    17    18   19
```

I know I can use `sample.iloc[i].shift(m[i])` to achive what I want one by one or all by applying a loop. But I have a very large data set and it takes forever to complete.

So is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?
Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boolean slicing to select just the rows of interest for each shift operation.  It will still be slow if the `set` of `m` is large, but faster than what you have.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sample_col = ["col1","col2","col3","col4", "col5"]
sample_data = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20]]
sample = pd.DataFrame(data = sample_data, columns = sample_col)
m = [0,1,2,1]

marr = np.array(m)
for i in sorted(set(m)):
    if i==0:
        continue
    sample.loc[marr==i] = sample.loc[marr==i].shift(i, axis=1)
```

Comment: Can you help me understand Boolean Slicing? I am able to work with Pandas but I need some good optimizing techniques. I have just moved from R to Python. Can you suggest some good books for that? Your answer did the trick so thanks for that.

Comment: Boolean slicing is where you slice a data frame (or series) by passing an array of true and false values that are the same length as the data frame.  So if you have a data frame, `df`, with 95 rows, you can pull back a subset of the rows by indexing on an boolean array, `ix_bools`, of the same length (`ix_bools = array([True, False, True, True, ... ])`).  The expressions `df[ix_bools]` or `df.loc[ix_bools]` will return only rows where `ix_bools` is `True`.